# Product of 4-chlorobutan-1-ol treated with KOH in alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

I am looking at this problem:

> [image: help]

I thought the KOH in alcohol would support a nucleophilic attack of hydroxide on the haloalkane, so the product I would get is B (elimination of HCl). However, this seems to be incorrect.

Comment: KOH in alcohol is a reasonably strong base. By far the most acidic proton in the 4-chlorobutan-1-ol starting material is the -OH so the first species generated is the alkoxide of the chlorobutanol

Comment: @Waylander U want to say O neg will attack at position of CL

Comment: Yes, the formation of the [5] ring is energetically favoured, Cl- is a good leaving group. This will be a fast and irreversible reaction

Comment: @Waylander thank sirr

Comment: @Karsten thanks for editing

Comment: @DUDE_WITH_J would prefer if you write questions, as much as possible, in clear language and with minimal grammatical errors. We don't demand perfection; but please maintain so that questions remain salvageable. There are various examples of good questions being asked in a bad way.

Comment: Few helpful links to help with formatting: [Chem / MathJaX formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange), [Upright Vs Italics](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized). Welcome to ChemSE!

Comment: @HarikrishnanM vankam sir , I have asked a new question in clear language as you told just look at it and if you find any mistake pls tell